# Why socket does not set to non blocking mode?

Tags: sockets, winapi, common-lisp, wininet

I try to set my socket to non-blocking mode using `ioctlsocket`, but it returns `-1` and `WSAGetLastError` returns `10045` - Operation not supported. Why could that happen?

The code I write is rather specific, because it's not C++, but Lisp with Foreign Language Interface (it allows calling C and C++ functions from dll's), but really it doesn't matter, because everything else does work.

Here is the code:

```
(defconstant FIONBIO #x5421)
(setf socket-descriptor (socket AF_INET SOCK_STREAM IPPROTO_TCP))
...
(fli:with-dynamic-foreign-objects ((no-block (:unsigned :long) :initial-element 1))
  (ioctlsocket socket-descriptor FIONBIO no-block))
...
```

`socket-descriptor` - is just a socket descriptor, created with standard function `socket`

`FIONBIO` - a constant, I've found it's value just by googling it

`no-block` - a pointer to `u_long`, value of th u_long is `1`.

`ioctlsocket` returns -1 and `WSAGetLastError` returns 10045.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps at all, the error 10045 you get from `WSAGetLastError` is described as follows:

[image]

**EDIT**
On my Windows system, I checked the value of `FIONBIO` in the debugger, and it should be `0x8004667E`.

It's defined like this in both `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` in the Windows 8 SDK:

```
#define _IOW(x,y,t)  (IOC_IN|(((long)sizeof(t)&IOCPARM_MASK)<<16)|((x)<<8)|(y))
#define FIONBIO      _IOW('f', 126, u_long) /* set/clear non-blocking i/o */
```

If you set an `unsigned int` equal to `FIONBIO`, then `0x8004667E` is what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I've read this, but still I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's a typically "useful" MS description - but it seems to indicate that there is some socket property or state that is necessary before you can set it to be nonblocking. I'll update the answer if I can find more clues.

Comment: OMG, thank you really much, it works! I had an idea that FIONBIO could be incorrect, but couldn't find another possible value.

Comment: "I checked the value of FIONBIO in the debugger, and it should be 0x8004667E". This is about as unlikely as it gets. It will be a single-bit value.

Comment: @EJP - Just clarified my sources in the edit, it might be unlikely, but that's how it's defined and that's solved the OP's problem. Is this just a Winsock thing?